# Convert pandas aggregation to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to do an aggregation which needs to show cities which have not less than 10 restaurants and restaurants having at least 100 votes, and to find out the 7 cities with the highest
AverageCostForTwo

I know how to do it in pandas, which will be in the following way:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_filtered = df[df.groupby('City')['RestaurantName'].transform('nunique') >= 10]
df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['Votes'] >= 100]

df_city_avg = df_filtered.groupby('City')['AverageCostForTwo'].mean().reset_index()
df_top_cities = df_city_avg.sort_values(by='AverageCostForTwo', ascending=False).head(7)
```

But I am not sure how can I perform this aggregation in elastic, any suggestions or ideas would be really helpful, I am a bit lost for this.

This is how my data looks like: [Data](https://gist.github.com/irenehawkins12/991eb15b7d4d3f572e57574bd0d17004)

Answer (score -1):

Following might be the solution for aggregation in Elasticsearch. Here it will return top 7 cities with the highest average cost for two, where each city has at least 10 restaurants and each restaurant has at least 100 votes.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"range": {"Votes": {"gte": 100}}},
        {"terms": {"City.keyword": {"size": 10, "min_doc_count": 10}}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {"field": "City.keyword"},
      "aggs": {
        "avg_cost": {
          "avg": {"field": "AverageCostForTwo"},
          "order": {"_avg": "desc"}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "sort": [{"cities>avg_cost": {"order": "desc"}}],
  "size": 7
}
```

Comment: `RestaurantName` is of type keyword, will the size metric work still? the output of a the query is a bit different from the one i got in pandas

Comment: You're right `size` parameter may not work as expected when applied to `terms` aggregation on the `RestaurantName` field since it's a type of `keyword`. If it doesn't work try also with `cardinality` aggregation.